# Use of has or have?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> The feedback from the small amount of people in Africa that has been so lucky to receive a blanket is incredible.

I would want to change the word 'has' to 'have'.

Comment: Yes, definitely change "has" to "have". Also, definitely change "the small amount of people" to "the few people".

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Isn't it a single amount, as in one small amount of people?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change to 'have' because it is a plural number of people that have received a blanket.  I would change 'small amount' of people to 'small number' of people.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above and would move "is incredible" closer to the subject of the feedback.  Also, it may sound better to use *who* instead of *that*:  The feedback is incredible from the few people in Africa who have been so lucky to receive a blanket.

Why use *have* instead of *has*?  If the number of people or subjects is more than one, plural in other words, then use the plural form of the verb.

Answer (score 0):

The linking verb should be has not have.  The subject is feedback, which is a singular, and not people; therefore, has is correct.